# Which elementary objects are cached by Python

Tags: python, memory-management, python-internals

It is fairly well known that Python (or at least CPython) caches a few first integers. That is, the following holds

```py
a = 1
b = 1
print(a is b)  # True
```

while also

```py
a = 1000
b = 1000
print(a is b)  # False
```

More broadly we can use the method listed below to see which elementary objects are cached (or "are singletons", if you prefer).

```py
def does_survive_pickling(obj):
    after_pickling = pkl.loads(pkl.dumps(obj))
    return obj is after_pickling
```

My questions are

- What are the objects which exhibit this behavior? (say, 'survives' the pickling method)

  - In my CPython 3.9.1 they are at least ints in [-5, 256] (same goes for corresponding characters, i.e. 8bit ACII), `()`, `None`, `True`, `False` and `Ellipsis`. Are there any others?
- What are the conditions on which the number and kinds of these objects depends?

  - I suppose that the Python implementation matters greatly.
  - What else (say, for CPython)? Version? Hardware (e.g. 32 bit vs. 64 bit processor)? Anything other?
- Is it possible to find these information somewhere? (in documentation ?)

I will be glad for any comments, answers or useful links. Thank you!

Perhaps the behavior of CPython is the only one that really matters to me. Yet, information regarding PyPy and others are welcome for curiosity's sake.

---

For the background, I am working on a library which needs to manage its memory resources. Thus, I strive to learn more about Python memory management. In this case, I am interested in the memory footprint of pickled-unpickled objects (more generally serialized-deserialized).

Say, you start with a bunch of objects with intertwined inner structures. What happens (how much the memory consumption rises) if each of these objects is saved to disk and loaded again?

If they are some nested lists with 1s, it is quite different from the same lists with 1000s.

Comment: "Is it possible to find these information somewhere?" - Yes, in the source code, as these are just implementation details. The second part of your question is very broad and a different question in itself, which makes your whole question much too broad for SO...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I understand that it is probably a deeply hidden small implementation detail. Nevertheless, I don't know that for sure. If it is really a very volatile feature, I will keep my hands off it. But maybe (again, I don't know, that's why I am asking) it is more general behavior fairly stable between Python versions (or maybe even implementations). In that case, it is useful to know. ... For example `iter` for `dict` in insertion order used to be a CPython's implementations detail, now it is a required feature (however, understand that the level of detail is quite different here).

Comment: The preservation of insertion order was an implementation detail in only one version of CPython, immediately preceding its promotion to language feature. I believe it was announced as such at the time as well: it was intentionally rolled out one version early as a test case.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on implementation details is a recipe for future disasters...

Object caching is an implementation detail and which objects are actually cached may change in any new Python version without any warning.

If you have a lot of large read-only objects most of which are equals, then you should considere implementing special processing at the `pickle` module level, such as the special `__reduce__` method, the pair `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`, or using out of band data processing. Unfortunately, it is very hard to know what is the best way for your actual use case. My opinion is that you should dig deeper in the `pickle` module documentation in order to find whether a *documented* way to save memory can be used.

Comment: I agree that some kind of a "hard-dependency" (if it changes, program breaks) would be really a problem in this case. However, I meant to use of only for more accurate estimate but just an estimate. Thus, more or less minor differences in implementation would not be a problem. Thanks for tip on pickle's special methods!